# What is roughly the Lorentz factor between interstellar and inter-galaxycluster space?

Tags: gravity, time-dilation

Could someone provide a rough estimate for the average Lorentz Factor caused by gravitational time dilation between some point in interstellar space in our vicinity within the Milky Way galaxy and some point in the void in-between galaxy clusters?

Comment: I suppose you can estimate the galaxy's gravitational potential from the Sun's orbital speed, 230 km/s. Using $\gamma^{-2}=1-2(v/c)^2$, that's $\gamma\approx$ 1 + 5.886e-7